# how to call a web service function form a different server?

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service with a import function i want to call from a c# application on another server

how do i call it

I can go to this url to invoke it:

http://site.co.uk/bespoke/WebService.asmx/Import

i want to call it from within my service on start:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
       //What do i do in here?
    }
```

Comment: Checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DPEden that is [just an improved version of the WebClient, and only usable in .NET 4.5](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/winappswithcsharp/thread/31f63b75-22c6-42e0-8c4f-4794cfea7737), perhaps you meant to mention the [HTTPClient from the WCF Starter Kit](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/03/13/httpclient-in-the-wcf-rest-starter-kit-preview-2.aspx). However, I'd go with Shedal's answer and use Add Service Reference.

Comment: @CodeCaster actually, http://nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/2.0.20126.16343 is compatible with .NET 4.0.  And, no, I did not mean the one from WCF Starter Kit as the project was deprecated a long time ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) feature.

Your web service seems to be a SOAP service. So if you wanted to call it "manually" (without any SOAP client libraries), you would have to manually implement the protocol-level stuff (such as XML-based SOAP envelope). This is highly discouraged.

If you use the feature I mentioned above, then Visual Studio will generate classes and objects for you, so you will be able to call the web service's method via a method on a local stub class.

Comment: once i have added it as a service refence could you give an example of how i am going to use this?

Comment: @Beginner first try adding it :) Normally it generates an example for you.

Comment: Right-click the generated reference and choose "View in object browser". You will see all the methods that you can call.